# Different Uncaught ReferenceError for same situations

Tags: javascript, scope, initialization, hoisting, uncaught-reference-error

I don't understand why for these same situations console returns two different outputs

```
console.log(a);
let a = 1;
```

console says a is not defined

and here

```
function a1() {
    console.log(a);
    let a = 1;
}
a1();
```

console says Cannot access 'a' before initialization
Isn't it supposed to return "Cannot access 'a' before initialization" in both cases? Because we use the let declaration for declaring variables and they are in TDZ in both cases? Why does it say a is not defined?

Why does it work so? Is hoisting of variables in a global scope different from hoisting within block scope?

Comment: You're testing this in a REPL or a browser console (which is basically a REPL) and you're not getting accurate behaviour as if you had run a JS file. That's really about it. FF console does report a TDZ error for the first block of code. Whatever you're using is just running it line by line, I suppose. Just run the code as you should and don't draw conclusions from how a random REPL interprets some lines of code.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77411438/different-uncaught-referenceerror-for-same-situations#comment136471428_77411438) That is: Test code in a real environment, not in the console's REPL. Depending on which one it is, the console REPL does *several* non-standard things in the name of being a useful debugging tool rather than an accurate representation of a simple scope.

Comment: *"Is hoisting of variables in a global scope different from hoisting within block scope?"* Not in a case like this, no: https://jsfiddle.net/yd0xv6cg/ (Global scope is a bit special in some ways and I advise using modules to avoid putting code at global scope, but agian, what you're seing here is just console behavior.)

Comment: Remember that console executes one line at a time. So at the time it executes `console.log(a)` in the first example, it hasn't seen `let a = 1;`. It can't preduct the future, so it doesn't know that you're going to declare it. But when compiling a function, it can see everything, and sees that the declaration is after the use.

Comment: @Barmar - That's true, but it should be a `ReferenceError` in either case, since the code is trying to read the value of an undeclared identifier (if you take it line-by-line). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think the function compiler treats it more like a syntax error to have the use before the declaration.

Comment: @Barmar - Not in the normal case, no. In both cases, all the code in the scope is scanned for declarations, those are handled (modern ones left uninitialized, obsolete `var`-style ones initialized with `undefined`), and then the step-by-step code begins. So whether global scope or function scope, in a real situation, this is the "you can't access an uninitialized binding" error. In the REPL, if it goes statement-by-statement instead, it should have been `a is not defined` (https://jsfiddle.net/, e.g., as though there were no `let a`) and it is in Chrome's REPL, but apparently not in the OP's.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It _is_ in OP's REPL, they write that they get `a is not defined` in the first case. The second case is different because while it does go statement by statement, that first and only statement that defines the function is only complete at the `}` of course. Then you get a normal function call and that functions does throw the TDZ error as expected.

Comment: @CherryDT - LOL I **did** read that initially, then somehow forgot it between then and the above. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the way the console you used processes what you paste into it. Don't take any lesson from it and apply it outside the console. Console [REPLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) do several things that are slightly different from the way code really behaves, either at global or function scope (or module scope). Console REPLs are handy for several things, but don't extrapolate what they do to other environments without double-checking.

In your example the console evaluated each statement **without** scanning ahead to the next (this is true even if you paste the lines together with line breaks between them).. So first it evaluated `console.log(a);`, and since there was no declared identifier for `a` it gave you the standard `a is not defined`. **Then** it evaluated your `let a = 1;`

But that **isn't** how code is actually evaluated at global scope. If you have:

```
console.log(a);
let a = 1;
```

...the JavaScript engine first scans through all the code looking for declarations like `let a` (and `var a` and `function` and `class` declarations) and creates *bindings* (roughly, variables) for them. The bindings for modern declarations (`let`, `const`, `class`) are left uninitialized; old `var`-style bindings (`var`, `function` declarations) are initialized (with `undefined` or with the function, respectively). So then when it goes to evaluate the step-by-step code, it sees that `a` is *declared*, but not *initialized*, and gives you the `Cannot access 'a' before initialization` error:

```js
console.log(a);
let a = 1;
```

It gave you the second behavior when you used a function because the function isn't evaluated until it's complete, and teh evaluation works similarly to the global evaluation I described above, so the JavaScript engine knows that `a` is declared (but not initialized) and throws the appropriate error.